# Can 'apt search' display results as one-liners like 'apt-cache search' does?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, package-management, apt

I just recently discovered the shorthand versions of apt commands: `apt install` instead of `apt-get install`, `apt update` / `apt-get update`, `apt search` / `apt-cache search`. Is there a config setting to make `apt search` display results as one-liners, like `apt-cache search` does ? It's less output and usually I don't need the description to decide which package to install.

Comment: My `apt search` does show one-line results, similar to `apt-cache search`, but `apt` only shows a few results for a "bash" search, while `apt-cache` has dozens... What version of apt do you have? Surprisingly `apt` doesn't know the --version flag, while `apt-cache --version` says `apt 1.0.1ubuntu2 ...`. It seems plain apt is still under active development...?

Comment: Both searches for bash return 94 results here (ubuntu 14.04). And yes, it says "apt does not have a stable CLI interface yet" at the end.

Comment: in ubuntu 18.04, *apt search* still shows result in two lines with a empty line in between each result which is even worse. And when there is a long list of result, the most relevant one is normally on the top, but it's already disappeared, since you can only see the last few results on the screen. This makes the 'apt search' useless. It forces me to always add a grep pipe like _apt search python | grep '^python' | less_ . Looking for a clean one-liner solution.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing two orthogonal problems.

One is "I want to type less into my terminal to search for packages" and that can be solved by putting something like this into your `~/.bashrc` (or equivalent for other shells):

```
alias as="apt-cache search"
```

Then you just need to write `as foo` to do an `apt-cache search foo`. Configure this as you like.

Or your question is "I want the one-line search results even when I use `apt search`". In that case there indeed exists a config option:

```
apt search -o APT::Cache::Search::Version=1 foo
```

This is a lot to type, so you could either move this into a bash alias:

```
alias as="apt search -o APT::Cache::Search::Version=1"
```

Or you could put it into your apt config in `/etc/apt`:

```
Binary::apt::APT::Cache::Search::Version "1";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set alias **aptsearch** for `apt-cache search` command in **.bashrc** file in your home folder.
All current command aliaces can bee seen with `alias` command.